# syntax error in For loop script

Tags: bash, shell-script, syntax

I'm new in Linux and I also know this is a pretty common problem in the forum's questions but I have tried  several options and I can't solve this issue. I am trying to execute the following script:

```
!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do 
    asreml -r2 Prueba_"$i".as > stdout_"$i".txt &&
done
```

But I got the following error message:

```
bash: ./jobs1-2.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
bash: ./jobs1-2.sh: line 9: `done'
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: probably because of `&&`

Comment: replace `&&` by `;`

Comment: If you want to run asreml in the background, use a single `&`. `&&` connects **two** commands, and you did not provide one on the right-hand side. See Lists in the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, as the [commenters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349111/syntax-error-in-for-loop-script#comment617899_349111) have [shown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349111/syntax-error-in-for-loop-script#comment617911_349111), you have a syntax error inside the loop, which confused bash when it tried to find the end of the loop.

You probably meant to either:

- chain a second command after asreml that would run if asreml finished successfully ($? == 0); for example: `asreml -r2 Prueba_"$i".as > stdout_"$i".txt && echo asreml finished successfully` or
- put the asreml command into the background: `asreml -r2 Prueba_"$i".as > stdout_"$i".txt &`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and also appreciate to the commenters. Actually the problem was the two &&, the only way as it worked was replacing them  by ";" as glen jackman said, ASReml uses && to connect tow commands. What I don't know is if ASReml will start the next job even if the previous one fails.

Comment: @Fersal you don't need `;` either. And yes, this will start the next even if the previous one fails. If you don't want that, use `asreml -r2 . . .  || exit`. But this should be in a new question. Also, since Jeff answered your question, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Fersal, see [terdon's excellent explanation of the various control operators](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators/159514#159514) such as `&&` and `||` to decide when to execute a second command based on the success of the first one.

Comment: OK, actually my problem came back, now when I submit script with more jobs they do not work. I have tried this, but it still doesn't works.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do 
 asreml -r2 Prueba_"$i".as > Stdouts/stdout_"$i".txt || exit;
done

Comment: As terdon  said, if you have a new/ different problem, ask a new question. Link to this one if you think it would help.